# How to fix columns name of dataframe auto change after use merge or join?

Tags: python, pandas, join

i am using python 3.8, after use join or merge, my dataframe columns auto changes to (column name,) How could i fix it? i tried to use join, merge, and concat but it return the same result :((

here is some images about it

df_temp
[image]

df_us_ed_songs_pos[0]

[image]

both of them have save index is `Date`. after i use join, it become like this

```
df_temp.join(df_us_ed_songs_pos[0])
```

[image]

all name columns of `df_temp` has changed. Anyone know how to fix it? thanks

update:
columns name:
[image]
[image]
[image]

hmmm, now i can see that `df_temp` columns seem wrong, but i checked `name_us_ed_songs` and it seem normal?

Comment: I can not replicate the situation. Can you provide your data?

Comment: https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/nadintamer/top-tracks-of-2017 and https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/edumucelli/spotifys-worldwide-daily-song-ranking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could update the column names by using a `list comprehension` and taking off first and last char, like this:

```
df_temp.columns = [col[1:-1] for col in df_temp.columns]
```

Comment: yes, but i don't know why it's was happend.i don't know if it was about my laptop or python version, but after search i saw they all use join without change columns name like this :((. And i can't control the columns name after join if use this code like Track Name and Position

Comment: @robocon20x can you print df.columns for each df here?

Comment: i has added 3 more pic. Oh, i solved the problem, in columns i should use columns = name_us_ed_songs instead of [name_us_ed_songs] :((. thanks for help

Comment: I've reproduced your case in a new environment and it seems not giving that kind of problem. Maybe your input to the join is not a dataframe. Have you tried transforming your `df_us_ed_songs_pos[0]` to a dataframe? (`df_temp.join(df_us_ed_songs_pos[0].to_frame())`)

Comment: i solved the problem, thanks. index of df_temp first was multi index cause it's 2D array ( i used  [name_us_ed_songs]  and  name_us_ed_songs already a list. so i just need to add columns name from 1D array.